# Changed variable type in parent class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

So I have this class called Card, in this class I have an Image, I then have several other classes that are inheriting this class and those classes as well.

I have decided to create a new class that extends Image instead now though and use that instead of the Image class in my parent Card class. However, because of this it has messed up all of the other classes that are passing in an Image variable.

Do I need to change all of the instances of the old Image class to the new CardImage class or is there another way around this?

Example:

```
public class A {
  private Image image;

  public A(Image image){
    this.image = image;
  }
}

public class B extends A{

  public B(Image image){
    super(image);
  }      
}

public class CardImage extends Image{
   public CardImage(){

   }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to pass `CardImage` instances to the constructors of `A` and `B` in your given code. What exactly is 'messed up'?

Comment: How is it screwing up all the other classes? With what you have now, it should still work, because all CardImage objects are Image objects

Comment: When I tried changing my image variable in the Card class to a CardImage class, it is complaining about incompatible types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your all classes will use only the `CardImages` then changing all of them can be meaningfull. But if only class `A` will use the `CardImage` then don't change anything. Just cast the `Image` to `CardImage` in `A` and use it. Because of each `CardImages` also is an `Image`, compiler won't push you to change parameter types.

```
public class A {
  private Image image;

  public A(Image image){
    this.image = image;
  }

  public void methodWhichNeedsCardImage() {
    if(image instanceof CardImage) {
         CardImage cImage = (CardImage) image;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I did try this earlier on, but its coming up with the error "Exception in thread "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image cannot be cast to com.mygdx.cards.CardImage"

Comment: Then use `instanceof`. It seems you are not creating class `A` always with a `CardImage`.

Comment: Thats done it! Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Good software design saves you the headaches and errors that arise when you have to make cascading changes to your code. If you find yourself thinking, "hmm, If I make this one little change, I'll have to change every reference to XYZ class" you're probably doing something wrong.

**Now to your question:** When it comes to inheritance, extending `Image` implies that every instance of `CardImage` is itself `Image`. Therefore, it is perfectly valid to pass a `CardImage` to the constructor of class `A` or `B` as in your example.

**Note:** When you extend the `Image` class, you need to be careful when/if you override its methods that you honor its method contracts (e.g. the `hashCode` method). So long as you honor the contracts made by the super class, your extension should not break your code.

Also, make sure you extend the correct class: `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and thats what I figured initially but when I tried changing my Image variable, it gave me an error that it was an incompatible type.